# How to filter map collection with helper method usage which prevent nullPointerException

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream, java-11

I have a method like:

```
static List<Employee> getEmployeesByFactoryAndTask(
      ProtectedMap<String, Factory> factoryMap, String factoryName, Task task) {

    return factoryMap.values().stream()
        .filter(factory -> factory.getName().equals(factoryName))
        .map(Factory::getEmployees)
        .flatMap(Optional::stream)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .filter(employee -> employee.getTask().equals(task))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

which assume filter `Employees` collection by `factoryName` and `Task` enum parameters.

Above code works fine but I want to use helper method `find` in my ProtectedMap class like:

```
public class ProtectedMap<T, U> extends HashMap<T, U> {
    public Optional<U> find(T key) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(super.get(key));
    }
}
```

to get the same result.

So far my method looks like:

```
return factoryMap
        .find(factoryName)
        .stream()
        .map(Factory::getEmployees)
        .flatMap(Optional::stream)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getTask, Function.identity()));
```

but I don't know where I suppose to put the second method call `find` which will filter by `Task` to get desribale effect. As a side note, Factory contains two fields: `Optional<List<Employees>>` and `String` which is a name of factory. 
I will be grateful for a suggestion on how to solve a problem.

Comment: What's what you really want to achieve? You want all employees from a given factory which have the given task?

Comment: Yes, I want a list of employee filtered by two criteria with find method Usage.

Comment: First of all, stop your `Factory` from wrapping collections into optionals. An empty collection is already sufficient to signal that there are no elements. Then, you can just use `return factoryMap .find(factoryName) .map(f -> f.getEmployees().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap( Employee::getTask, Function.identity()))) .orElse(Collections.emptyMap());`

Comment: There is no point in trying to bring in that trivial `find` method at all costs. If you want a particular task, don’t collect into a `Map` at all: instead of `.collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getTask, Function.identity()))`, use `.filter(employee -> employee.getTask().equals(task)) .collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: @Holger
Thanks for your response. I know that List wrapped by Optional and insisting on using the method `find` is not a good idea but I suppose to meet requirements which aren't dependent on me.

Comment: My second comment is independent from the “list wrapped inside optional” issue. Just use `return factoryMap .find(factoryName) .stream() 
  .flatMap(f -> f.getEmployees().map(Collection::stream).orElse(null)) 
  .filter(employee -> employee.getTask().equals(task)) .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @Holger Your answer fits in a little with my previous solution stream from my question. If you think that this will be enough and there is no need to overuse this devilry find method I trust you. Thanks for your response.

Comment: The models for `Factory` and `Employee` would have been good to add. Apart from which, is the `factoryMap` in the input a map of `factoryName` and `factory`? Reason to ask it is the use of values in one block of code while using factoryName as a key in another : `factoryMap.find(factoryName)` Vs `factoryMap.values().stream().filter(factory -> factory.getName().equals(factoryName))`... All of that set aside, have you explored using [`Map.getOrDefault](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-)?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code which handles your requirement but `getEmployeesByFactoryAndTask` also returns `Optional<List<Employee>>` and as I can understand this return value can be handled by you.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collector;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;


enum Task {
    QA, DEVELOPEMENT, DESIGN
}

class Employee {
    long id;
    String name;
    Task task;

    Employee(long id, String name, Task task) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.task = task;
    }

    Task getTask() {
        return task;
    }
}

class Factory {
    List<Employee> employees;

    Factory() {}

    Factory(List<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }

    public Optional<List<Employee>> getEmployees() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(employees);
    }
}

class ProtectedMap<T, U> extends HashMap<T, U> {
    public Optional<U> find(T key) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(super.get(key));
    }
}

public class Main57989215 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Employee> employees1 = new ArrayList<>();
        employees1.add(new Employee(21, "Alen", Task.DESIGN));
        employees1.add(new Employee(31, "Herry", Task.QA));
        employees1.add(new Employee(41, "John", Task.DEVELOPEMENT));
        employees1.add(new Employee(51, "Martin", Task.QA));
        employees1.add(new Employee(61, "Jack", Task.DESIGN));


        List<Employee> employees2 = new ArrayList<>();
        employees2.add(new Employee(121, "John", Task.DESIGN));
        employees2.add(new Employee(131, "Porter", Task.QA));
        employees2.add(new Employee(141, "Cena", Task.DEVELOPEMENT));
        employees2.add(new Employee(151, "Luther", Task.QA));
        employees2.add(new Employee(161, "Dinga", Task.DESIGN));


        ProtectedMap<String, Factory> factoryMap = new ProtectedMap<>();
        factoryMap.put("factory1", new Factory(employees1));
        factoryMap.put("factory2", new Factory(employees2));
        factoryMap.put("factory3", new Factory());

        System.out.println(getEmployeesByFactoryAndTask(factoryMap, "factory1", Task.QA));
        System.out.println(getEmployeesByFactoryAndTask(factoryMap, "factory1", Task.QA));
        System.out.println(getEmployeesByFactoryAndTask(factoryMap, "factory2", Task.DEVELOPEMENT));
        System.out.println(getEmployeesByFactoryAndTask(factoryMap, "factory3", Task.DESIGN));
        System.out.println(getEmployeesByFactoryAndTask(factoryMap, "factory4", Task.QA));
    }

    static Optional<List<Employee>> getEmployeesByFactoryAndTask(ProtectedMap<String, Factory> factoryMap, String factoryName, Task task) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(factoryMap.find(factoryName)).orElse(Optional.empty())
                .flatMap(factory -> Optional.ofNullable(factory.getEmployees())
                        .orElse(Optional.empty()).map(employees -> employees.stream()
                                .filter(employee -> employee.getTask().equals(task)).collect(Collectors.toList())));
    }
}
```